# how to retrieve golang code from shared play.golang.org url

Tags: go

I need to read golang code from the play.golang.org link and save to a .go file. I'm wondering if there is any public API support for play.golang.org. I googled but no hints. Has anyone attempted anything similar?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get the text of a shared playground program, append ".go" to the URL.  For example, you can get the text of the program at https://play.golang.org/p/HmnNoBf0p1z with https://play.golang.org/p/HmnNoBf0p1z.go.

You can upload a program by posting the program text to https://play.golang.org/share. The response is the ID of the shared program. This program uploads stdin to the playground and prints the ID of the uploaded program to stdout:

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "https://play.golang.org/share", os.Stdin)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    resp, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    io.Copy(os.Stdout, resp.Body)
}
```

Assuming the above program is in upload.go, the following shell script prints `HmnNoBf0p1z`.

```
go run upload.go << EOF
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
}
EOF
```

If you want to download the program as a file using a browser, then add the query `?download=true` to the .go URL. Example: https://play.golang.org/p/HmnNoBf0p1z.go?download=true

Comment: Cool, I didn't know about that!

Comment: The playground now supports multiple files (ex: https://play.golang.org/p/KLZR7NlVZNX) but I don't yet see a way to download each file individually. https://play.golang.org/p/KLZR7NlVZNX.go just dumps the whole content.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways that I know one of which is described by @ThunderCat. Another simple solution is go to the URL https://play.golang.org/p/HmnNoBf0p1z and Press `Ctrl+save` on the page it will be downloaded as a `.go` file.